# Next n values in pandas loop with Python

Tags: python

I need the row and the next 4 rows too in loop. Any way to do that?

```
data = pd.read_csv('status.csv')
for i, row in data.iterrows():
    row
    row+1
    row+2
    row+3
    row+4
```

Comment: You can use list slicing for pandas dataframes.

Comment: You would be much better off not using a loop at all. Post a new question with the problem you are facing, that made you think you need a loop, and you will get much faster and better ways to do it without looping the raws in a `pandas` dataframe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can slice rows in dataframe using `loc`. More info [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#slicing-ranges).

You can get iterator of row + next 4 rows using:

```py
data.loc[i:i+5].iterrows()
```

Full Example:

```py
for i in range(len(data.index)):
    for idx, row in data.loc[i:i+5].iterrows():
       print(idx, row)
```

Answer (score 0):

By specifying a `chunksize` to `pd.read_csv` to consume csv data as *iterator*:

```
df = pd.read_csv('status.csv', chunksize=5)
for chunk in df:
    # do processing over chunk of 5 rows
```

where `chunk` is a `Dataframe`, so you might need to further `for i, row in chunk.iterrows():`

Comment: This will get all rows in chunks of 5. Whereas, I think the question is looking for  each row, with it's consecutive 4 rows. So first row from top with next 4 rows, then second row from top with next 4 rows etc.

Comment: @RithinChalumuri, I don't think so, when looking at the OP's loop with 5 consecutive rows on each iteration